# ReactJS does not support svg filters?

Tags: reactjs

Wrote filter inner shadow, but unfortunately gives an error ()

```
export function InnerShadow(props:InnerShadowProps):ReactElement<any> {
    return (
        <defs>
            <filter id="inner-shadow" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
                <feComponentTransfer in=SourceAlpha> // : error TS1005: '{' expected.
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 0"/>
                </feComponentTransfer> // : error TS1005: '}' expected.
                <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"/>
                <feOffset dx="0" dy="0" result="offsetblur"/>
                <feFlood flood-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" result="color"/>
                <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"/>
                <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" />
                <feMerge>
                    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" /><feMergeNode />
                </feMerge>
            </filter>
        </defs>
    );
}
```

And in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html) of the  I have not found.

Question - have I missed something or ReactJS do not support filters and my filter will never work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to quote the `in` attribute in the `feComponentTransfer` component.

The component should look like this

```
<feComponentTransfer in="SourceAlpha">
```

Rather than

```
<feComponentTransfer in=SourceAlpha>
```

Comment: Thank you for found error, but the ultimate problem was in the compiler. Typescript doesn't know about svg from react.